# how to accelerate the speed of unzip large file in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, zip, unzip

Now we have the file structure like this and
[image]
and each zip file contains only 1 file, but some file in zipfile is more than 5GB.

I use the `zipfile` module in python to unzip them, and it takes 1 hour to unzip a single aip file. How to accelerate the speed? And I want to cut the data into 4 parts as limit by the storage. Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you use `unzip -l` to provide a listing of the contents of the zip file that takes an hour to unzip? What kind of machine is this on? Unzipping 5GB should only take about 30 seconds to a minute.